# Trying to pass few variables to linux session from a flat file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, environment-variables

I need to export around 10 variables to a session. To do this, I've put all these 10 variables in a flat file and trying to launch this flat file from shell using

> *sh flatfile*

But these variables aren't set at session level. If i echo these within the flatfile, it is correctly displaying those. Any leads how I can bring these to the current session ?

Comment: You need to source the file: `. flatfile` or `source flatfile`.